# Blend meshes, but no background. Three.js

Tags: three.js, blending

I need to perform additive blending for two meshes in Three.js. But I don't want to blend background also. Just now I blend everything in my scene.

**Could You help me to blend objects properly?**

I have the following fragment shader (black pixels should be transparent):

```
uniform vec3 color;
uniform float time;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec3 pixelColor = color*(sin((vUv.y + time)*40.));
    float alpha = pixelColor[0]+pixelColor[1]+pixelColor[2];
    if (alpha<0.)   {
        alpha=0.;
    }   else    {
        alpha=1.;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(pixelColor, alpha);
}
```

Create materials (uniforms contain only color):

```
var material1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms1,
        vertexShader: vShader,
        fragmentShader: fShader,
        transparent: true,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    });
```

And meshes:

```
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material1);
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);
```

Set background (without background everything looks good):

```
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('skyblue'));
```

**Do I made a mistake or, in case of RTFM, could You help with a link? Google did not help me.**

Comment: there are details missing and it's unclear what you want to achieve, please supply a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: https://codepen.io/zlon/pen/dJJdmB  I need this, but with renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('skyblue'));

Comment: One solution is to set the CSS `background-color: skyblue;` and `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );`. Is that acceptable?

Comment: It is acceptable in terms of result. Another variant is to put plane as background. But it looks like not elegant webGL solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?